# How to record multiple x/y coords of current mouse position with a key press in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pyautogui

Using `pyautogui` I can get the x/y coordinate of the mouse position manually by using:

```
pyautogui.position()
```

I want to create a loop that will record the x/y coordinate of where my mouse is hovering every time I press 'a' and then stop recording when I press 'b'.

Comment: And what have you tried? What did not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: -
Here is a short Python 3 program that will constantly print out the position of the mouse cursor:

```
#! python3
import pyautogui, sys
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        print(positionStr, end='')
        print('\b' * len(positionStr), end='', flush=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n')
```

The moveTo() function will move the mouse cursor to the X and Y integer coordinates you pass it. The None value can be passed for a coordinate to mean “the current mouse cursor position”. For example:

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200.
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(None, 500)  # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 500.
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(600, None)  # moves mouse to X of 600, Y of 500.
```

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html